# How to call mongoose findone inside foreach and wait request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have list of items which I itterate using `forEach`. I check type of each item, and for one item type I need to send request to mongoDB, and wait for response to use it further.

If it is important - I use forEach to use socket.io emit in timeout.

Here is how I itterate list now:

```
questionList.forEach((question) => {
    let respName = "";
    let respObj = question;

    if (question.type === "some_type") {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_name" 
    } else if (question.type === "some_typeN") {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_nameN"
    } else if (question.type === "some_type4") {
      respName = "some_name4"
      respObj = getBlockStats(handle, block);
    } else {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_nameX"
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      io.emit(respName, respObj);
    }, offset);

    offset += offsetIncrease;
});
```

Here is function I call in the loop:

```
const getBlockStats = (handle, block) => {
  return GameAnswers.findOne({ handle })
    .then(gameAnswers => {
      let maxQuesstionInBlock = gameAnswers.answers
        .reduce((a, b) => {
          return (parseInt(a.ownId) > parseInt(b.ownId) ? a : b)
        })
      let results = [];

      for (let i = 1; i <= maxQuesstionInBlock.ownId; i++) {
        let team1AllAnswers = gameAnswers.answers
          .filter(el => {
            return el.blockId === block
          })
          .filter((el) => {
            return el.team === "team1"
          })
          .filter((el) => {
            return parseInt(el.ownId) === i
          });

        let team1CorrectAnswers = team1AllAnswers
          .filter(el => {
            return el.correct === "true"
          });

        let team2AllAnswers = gameAnswers.answers
          .filter(el => {
            return el.blockId === block
          })
          .filter((el) => {
            return el.team === "team2"
          })
          .filter((el) => {
            return parseInt(el.ownId) === i
          });

        let team2CorrectAnswers = team2AllAnswers
          .filter(el => {
            return el.correct === "true"
          });

        let result = {
          "question": i,
          "team1": {
            "all": team1AllAnswers.length,
            "correct": team1CorrectAnswers.length,
            "percent": team1CorrectAnswers.length * 100 / team1AllAnswers.length
          },
          "team2": {
            "all": team2AllAnswers.length,
            "correct": team2CorrectAnswers.length,
            "percent": team2CorrectAnswers.length * 100 / team2AllAnswers.length
          }
        }

        results.push(result);

      }
      return results;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("no GameAnswers find err -> ", err);
    });
}
```

Currently my request to mongoDB happens only after forEach itterated through all list. And for `some_type4` in `respObj` I have empty object. I need to have resonse from server in it (i.e. request to stop loop and wait for result, after that go further)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to use **async/await** to handle the asynchronous db calls and **for..of** loop to iterate over your array. You couldn't use **forEach** as async/await doesn't work in it.

You can refer [this](https://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html) to learn about async/await.(Focus section **7.2**)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. I know how that I need to use async/await or Promise, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue using async/await

```
const questionAction = async (question) => {
    let respName = "";
    let respObj = question;

    if (question.type === "some_type") {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_name" 
    } else if (question.type === "some_typeN") {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_nameN"
    } else if (question.type === "some_type4") {
      respName = "some_name4"
      respObj = await getBlockStats(handle, block); 
    } else {
      // some not important code
      // respName = "some_nameX"
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      io.emit(respName, respObj);
    }, offset);

    offset += offsetIncrease;
};

(async () => {
  for (const question of questionList) {
    await questionAction(question);
  }
})()
```